# How can I run an application and do not show the console?

Tags: c#

I've got a console application and I want to run it from another application. But when I invoke it from code--to call program I use ActiveXObject--it shows the console. How do I get it to not show the console? I mean, the program works but console is shown.

Comment: Have you considered using a class library instead?

Comment: code in console app. I can't use in Silverlight project. It has unavaible methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the application a *Windows Application* instead of a *Console Application* it will not show or open (or use) a Console.  Your code can stay the same - and the application will still function (without ever creating a `Form` or `Window`).

That being said, if you control the "other" application, you may want to consider making a class library instead of a separate Application.  This would allow you to just include and run code within the library without starting a separate process.

Comment: @user1432980 Just change it to "Windows Application" in the project settings, and it will no longer open a console.  Nothing else has to change.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Ok so you mean create a Windows Form App. Erase Form1.vb and then create a Module1.vb with a sub Main(). I tried that but it gives me a runtime error "A startup" form has not been specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it as a Windows Forms application with a hidden window. That's just one possibility like Reed Copsey pointed out, i used it once because i needed to process some specific Window Messages.

Comment: No need to do this.  You don't need to make a window/form at all.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Was just looking for the project template, then remembered it's in the project properties. Thanks for the info :)